# Java PropertiesConfiguration

Tags: java

I built project to exe file, when i run exe file it has error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.
```

Could you tell me why?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check  whether jar file containing org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration class is available in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Your commons-configuration jar file missed in your classpath. Please make sure required jar is in classpath and redeploy again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include required lib to your exe file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. create a folder with all your needed libraries
2. in a shell (`cmd.exe`) run: `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<path to libraries folder>`
3. run your executable

*hth*